# Selenium Mac Salesforce

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java, test-strategy

I'm trying to automate to log in into `salesforce` account and after it logs in I want it to `click` on contact `button`, but for some reason it won't, I even wrote a different `function` just for it to click it, but after it logs in it freezes in the same page after the screen maximizes.
[image]

And this is my code:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;



public class browser {
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
    
    System.out.println("Start Test Case");
    initialize();
    LoginSFDC();
    WrongUNandPW();
    }




private static WebDriver driver = null;

public static void initialize() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }



public static void LoginSFDC() throws InterruptedException {
    
    
    driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("arnish.chakma-fliw@force.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("lolboy845JJ");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='rememberUn']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Login']")).click();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    
    WebElement contactbtn = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='trial-subscribe-now']"));
    contactbtn.click();

    
    
    
    driver.close();
    
    
    
}



public static void WrongUNandPW() throws InterruptedException {
    
    
    driver.get("https://login.salesforce.com/");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("arnish.chakma-fliw@force123.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='password']")).sendKeys("lolboy845JJ123");
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='rememberUn']")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='Login']")).click();
    
    
    
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    
    
    
}


}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I see a google chrome notification there.

You need to first handle/disable that notification first.

To do that, you can use the following code snippet when initializing a browser

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
.
.
.
ChromeOptions cOptions = new ChromeOptions();
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", driverPath);
cOptions.addArguments("--disable-notifications");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(cOptions);
```

`--disable-notification` will help you dismiss those notifications.

If you want to disable infobars, you can use `cOptions.addArguments("disable-infobars");`

Comment: will try it out and let you know, thank you @Kenil Fadia